# Catching the name of a button during post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, button, input

If I have an `<input>` of type submit, with a name, I can catch that name in my MVC model when I use it to post. Is the same not possible with a `<button>`, of type submit and the same name?

If I use for example `name="ButtonName"`, my property ButtonName get's the input's value. For some reason this doesn't work with a button element.

The reason I want to use a button instead of input, is that i need to have more than text inside the button (including a picture).

Comment: Sounds like you may be looking for another hidden input to hold your extra value, instead of trying to shoehorn it into the submit button somehow.

Comment: But how would I show which button I click by using a hidden field?

Comment: I'm not positive what processing asp does on your HTML, but in general `input type='submit'` should work the same as `button type='submit'`.  You will need a `name` attribute on either of them for them to be sent to the server.  Can you show example code?

Comment: I ended up scrapping another input, voiding the need for this. Thanks for trying anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the value of the hidden input by using a simple onclick Javascript function for each of your inputs.

```
function setHidden(sender){  
  document.getElementById("hidden1").value = sender.value;
}
```